# JWT refresh token [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

I am using `Tymon` pkg for JWT auth in Laravel 5.2

In my Kernel I have middlware:

```
'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
```

Anyone can explain me how to use it and how to set up refresh token in my app server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use refresh token middleware in routes or route groups.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'        =>  'api',
    'namespace'     =>  'API',
    'middleware'    =>  ['throttle', 'jwt', 'refresh'],
], function(){
    // Yor routes logic...
});
```

Please read more about refreshing token and review `jwt.php` config file for more details on refreshing tokens.